# How to test Web service from the brower - User Profile Service - GetUserByName

Tags: 2010, development, soap

I'm trying to get user image URL from User Profile Service using JavaScript/Jquery but haven't managed to get the correct tag. One of the reasons is because I can't identify the tags correctly. 
I think it's possible to enter the method with parameter into the URL and obtain an XML output in the browser, this would help me work out the correct tag to locate. Does anyone know the correct syntax for the url to perform this?

I have the code below as the starting point which outputs methods. 
`http://<server>/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx`.

Using SP 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually test OOTB SharePoint Web services from the browser, you first need to allow that from the web.config.

Open the web.config for Web services, located at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI`

Change:

```
<protocols>  
  <remove name="HttpPost" />
  <remove name="HttpGet" />
  <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost" />
</protocols>
```

to:

```
<protocols>  
  <add name="HttpPost" />
  <add name="HttpGet" />
  <add name="HttpPostLocalhost" />
</protocols>
```

Save, and navigate to `http://<server>/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx` from the browser.

The list of all available methods should appear. Click e.g. on `GetUserProfileByName` and you should see a page promptig you for parameters, e.g. `AccountName`.

**EDIT**
Another option would be to test, not from the browser, but from a dedicated test client tool, such as https://www.soapui.org/.

Comment: In the brower I see the list of methods, no promt box opens when clicking any of the methods.

Comment: Not a prompt _box_, simply a new page for the method, with text box for the parameters.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to edit the web.config so will try research more.
BTW the above codes are identical

Comment: "BTW the above codes are identical" --> yup, a mistake I fixed in my answer. Unfortunately, there's no other option than editing the web.config file to test from the browser. Or you can use a client tool to test ASMX Web service, such as https://www.soapui.org/.